# UML class diagram implementation Address-Addressbook

Tags: java

I have 2 class diagrams, class Address

```
+forename
+surename
+street
+houseno
+code
+state
+toString
```

second Addressbook

```
insert(address: Address)
toString()
searchSurename (surename:  string): Address[*] 
+searchForename(forename: string): Address[*]
```

i implemented address:

```
public class Address {

    public static String forename;
    public static String surename;
    public static String street;
    public static int houseno;
    public static int code;
    public static String state;
    public String toString(){
 return this.forename + this.surename + this.street + this.houseno + this.code + this.state;
            }
```

How can I implement Addressbook as easy as possible?

EDIT:

```
public class addressbook{

    private static ArrayList<Address> book;


public addressbook(){
   book = new ArrayList<Address>();
}
```

}

EDIT QUESTION:

Am I allowed to add new methods or attributes in a implementation outside the ones that we use in our class diagrams?

EDIT 2:

First try implementing method searchSurename with an ArrayList:

```
public static String searchSurename(String surename){
     boolean exist = false;

     if(this.addresses.isEmpty()){
         return null;
     }

     for(int i=0;i<this.addresses.size();i++) {
         if(this.addresses.get(i).getSurename() == surename) {
             exist=true;
             break;
         }

         if(exist) {
             return this.addresses.get(surename);
         } else {
             return this.addresses.get(surename);
         }
     }
 // return ?!?

}
```

The Program give me Errors at "this" at any line, maybe a mistake but I cant tell! It Looks a Little bit too difficult, I don't find any implementations where searching through a list is simple.

Comment: How about creating a class called adressbook, which have some list of adresses?

Comment: private static ArrayList<Adress> book; My first idea but i have Problems to write the correct implementation for searching in These Kind of structures

Comment: Some issues here, first, always try to specify the type of the fields, even if they are easy to find `+name:String`, second that all static members should be underlined. the next thing is address class `toString()` method, it's very bad designed, this is really unlogical to have an instance for showing static members. next, don't think si-sharp, in java we don't have string, it's `String`, the next thing is about arrays, there is no difference between `Address[*]` and `Address[]`.

Comment: How would you impelement the toString method correctly? And what do you mean with static members should be underlined. Underlinned in the class diagram?!

Comment: The Programm give me Errors at "this" at any line, maybe a mistake but i cant tell! It Looks a Little bit too difficult, i dont find any implementations where searching through a list is simple.

Comment: Correct spelling is "address", by the way

Answer (score 1):

You could implement it in a way like this. Look at the api for arrayList for using its methods.

```
public class Adressbook {

    List<Adress> adresses = new ArrayList<Adress>();

    public Adressbook(){
        adresses = new arraylist<Adress>();
    }

    public insert (Adress adress){
        adresses.add(adress)
    }

    public searchSurename(String Surename){
    }

    public searchForename(String forename){
    }

    public String toString(){
    }
```

ArrayList api:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: How can i implement the search methods? The only Thing i know is that i can use an for each Loop or an iterator if im not wrong.

Comment: @JamesRich if the size of the addresses is kinda huge, so search in a parallel manner, this [example](http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/07/java-thread-example.html#ai) may help.

Comment: @James Rich How about looping through the whole list of adresses and then compare if the object matches the search criteria? (:

As i wrote in my answer i suggest you take a look at the ArrayList api

Comment: I saw some Loop with an iterator and/or foreach Loop. I look after similiar implementations and test it.

Answer (score 0):

To have unique address use set collection interface

```
public class Adressbook {
    ....
    private Set<Adress> adresses = null;
    public Adressbook(){
        adresses = new HashSet<Adress>();
    }
    public void add(Adress adress){
        adresses.add(adress)
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: And how would you implement a method which search the forename of a Person?